# Storing data using Cron Job in CosmosDB using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cron, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My current use-case is to fetch data from one cosmos table and store it into second DB after doing some operations on data.

The data size can vary from 5k to 20k records.

I am using Spring boot for creating the cron job as well as cosmos connections.

So I have some question regarding it :

1. Which client or repository should I use ? (Async/reactive or normal)
2. I am thinking of using batches to save the data using saveAll(), I am bit confuse on reactive repository as it was giving me Request charges error when saving bulk data to DB.

Also if you guys have some examples for above usecase as well as any suggestions would be helpful to work on the required changes.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using saving data with synchronous manner and it took much time and was exceeding the cron job timings.

I also tried to save it asynchronous manner but it start giving me Request charge errors.

Here is code example :
Method :

```
public void saveData(Data data) {
   dataRepo.save(data).subscribe();
}
```

Repo :

```
public interface DataRepo extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<Data, String> {
}
```

Also I am using parallel stream for the same as I don't care of saving order

Comment: Please edit to provide specifics. Right now, you haven't really shared much, aside from a general set of requirements.